# Как перебрать все ячейки таблицы в колонке с заданным классом?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Написал функцию, которая

1. принимает строку поиска `searchValue`,
2. находит ячейку в таблице,
3. возвращает id ряда
4. и складывает id  в массив.

Для поиска по всей таблице все работает хорошо.
Хочу реализовать поиск по заданной колонке.

Допустим у меня есть колонка "phone" с классом `.phoneUser`,
требуется получить id рядов если значение нашлось в поле "phone".
Для этого планирую передавать класс как аргумент item='.phoneUser',

но вот так не работает:

```
$('#maintable tbody .phoneUser td').each(function(){
```

Хотел сделать вот так:

```
$('#maintable tbody '+item+' td').each(function(){
```

Пробовал вот так:

```
$('#maintable .phoneUser tbody  td')
```

но так же безрезультатно.
Ничего не находится.

**Ниже основной код функции:**

```
function showActiveItems(searchValue, item=''){
    var arrayWithId = []
    if (searchValue != '') {
        $('#maintable tbody td').each(function(){
            console.log($(this).text())
            if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue) > -1) {
                arrayWithId.push($(this).closest("tr").attr('id'));
            }
        });
    }
   ...
```

Код выше работает, задача добавить к поиску класс userPhone.
Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Если я правильно понял, и класс phoneUser указан у нужной ячейки, то `$('#maintable tbody td.phoneUser')`

Comment: Спасибо! Работает. Пробовал как вы написали, но добавлял пробел между td и .phoneUser, в этом была ошибка.